# Java - Getting all combinations of values in a two-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, combinatorics

This code fills in all possible combinations of values in a two-dimensional array and works fine in this example. However as you can see I hardcoded the index numbers appropriate for an array with these dimensions and "manually" nested the the for loops for the array with these dimensions...

There must be some way to rework this code so you can pass any `int[][]` as an argument to the method regardless of dimensions right?

With clever use of recursion or by using the `.length` attribute.. Kind of stuck at the moment and not seeing how to properly create the right nesting and flow.

```
public class Combinator {

    static int[][] arr2D = new int[2][2];

    static int[] values = new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    static int n;

    public static void combine() {

        for (int i: values) {
            arr2D[0][0] = i;

            for (int j: values) {
                arr2D[0][1] = j;

                for (int k: values) {
                    arr2D[1][0] = k;

                    for (int l: values) {
                        arr2D[1][1] = l;
                        printArr2D();
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void printArr2D() {

        for (int y = 0; y < arr2D.length; y++) {

            for (int x = 0; x < arr2D[y].length; x++) {
                System.out.print(arr2D[y][x] + " ");

                if (y == arr2D.length - 1 && x == arr2D[y].length - 1) {
                    System.out.print("printed out for the " + ++n + "th time.");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        combine();
    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to declare an array without size. You can use ArrayList: 

ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> matrix = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
matrix.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
matrix.get(0).add(ROW0Col0Number);
matrix.get(0).add(ROW0Col1Number);
matrix.get(1).add(ROW1Col0Number);

Comment: Just to point out you can give any kind of array as a argument to a method without even initializing it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want something like this:

```
public static void printCombinations2D(int width, int height, int... values) {
    int[][] idx = new int[height][width];
    LOOP: for (;;) {
        print2D(values, idx);
        for (int y = height - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
            for (int x = width - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
                if (++idx[y][x] < values.length)
                    continue LOOP;
                idx[y][x] = 0;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
private static void print2D(int[] values, int[][] idx) {
    for (int[] row : idx) {
        for (int i : row)
            System.out.print(values[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

You then call it like this:

```
printCombinations2D(2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
```

Or if you prefer:

```
int[] values = new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
printCombinations2D(2, 2, values);
```

If you want a 3x5 matrix of all combinations (beware: that is 1,000,000,000,000,000 matrices):

```
printCombinations2D(3, 5, 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
```

*Test*

```
printCombinations2D(3, 2, 7,8,9);
```

*Output*

```
7 7 7 
7 7 7 

7 7 7 
7 7 8 

7 7 7 
7 7 9 

7 7 7 
7 8 7 

7 7 7 
7 8 8 

7 7 7 
7 8 9 

7 7 7 
7 9 7 

7 7 7 
7 9 8 

7 7 7 
7 9 9 

7 7 7 
8 7 7 

7 7 7 
8 7 8 

7 7 7 
8 7 9 

7 7 7 
8 8 7 

7 7 7 
8 8 8 

7 7 7 
8 8 9 

7 7 7 
8 9 7 

7 7 7 
8 9 8 

7 7 7 
8 9 9 

7 7 7 
9 7 7 

7 7 7 
9 7 8 

7 7 7 
9 7 9 

7 7 7 
9 8 7 

7 7 7 
9 8 8 

7 7 7 
9 8 9 

7 7 7 
9 9 7 

7 7 7 
9 9 8 

7 7 7 
9 9 9 

7 7 8 
7 7 7 

7 7 8 
7 7 8 

7 7 8 
7 7 9 

7 7 8 
7 8 7 

7 7 8 
7 8 8 

7 7 8 
7 8 9 

7 7 8 
7 9 7 

7 7 8 
7 9 8 

7 7 8 
7 9 9 

7 7 8 
8 7 7 

7 7 8 
8 7 8 

7 7 8 
8 7 9 

7 7 8 
8 8 7 

7 7 8 
8 8 8 

7 7 8 
8 8 9 

7 7 8 
8 9 7 

7 7 8 
8 9 8 

7 7 8 
8 9 9 

7 7 8 
9 7 7 

7 7 8 
9 7 8 

7 7 8 
9 7 9 

7 7 8 
9 8 7 

7 7 8 
9 8 8 

7 7 8 
9 8 9 

7 7 8 
9 9 7 

7 7 8 
9 9 8 

7 7 8 
9 9 9 

7 7 9 
7 7 7 

7 7 9 
7 7 8 

7 7 9 
7 7 9 

7 7 9 
7 8 7 

7 7 9 
7 8 8 

7 7 9 
7 8 9 

7 7 9 
7 9 7 

7 7 9 
7 9 8 

7 7 9 
7 9 9 

7 7 9 
8 7 7 

7 7 9 
8 7 8 

7 7 9 
8 7 9 

7 7 9 
8 8 7 

7 7 9 
8 8 8 

7 7 9 
8 8 9 

7 7 9 
8 9 7 

7 7 9 
8 9 8 

7 7 9 
8 9 9 

7 7 9 
9 7 7 

7 7 9 
9 7 8 

7 7 9 
9 7 9 

7 7 9 
9 8 7 

7 7 9 
9 8 8 

7 7 9 
9 8 9 

7 7 9 
9 9 7 

7 7 9 
9 9 8 

7 7 9 
9 9 9 

7 8 7 
7 7 7 

7 8 7 
7 7 8 

7 8 7 
7 7 9 

7 8 7 
7 8 7 

7 8 7 
7 8 8 

7 8 7 
7 8 9 

7 8 7 
7 9 7 

7 8 7 
7 9 8 

7 8 7 
7 9 9 

7 8 7 
8 7 7 

7 8 7 
8 7 8 

7 8 7 
8 7 9 

7 8 7 
8 8 7 

7 8 7 
8 8 8 

7 8 7 
8 8 9 

7 8 7 
8 9 7 

7 8 7 
8 9 8 

7 8 7 
8 9 9 

7 8 7 
9 7 7 

7 8 7 
9 7 8 

7 8 7 
9 7 9 

7 8 7 
9 8 7 

7 8 7 
9 8 8 

7 8 7 
9 8 9 

7 8 7 
9 9 7 

7 8 7 
9 9 8 

7 8 7 
9 9 9 

7 8 8 
7 7 7 

7 8 8 
7 7 8 

7 8 8 
7 7 9 

7 8 8 
7 8 7 

7 8 8 
7 8 8 

7 8 8 
7 8 9 

7 8 8 
7 9 7 

7 8 8 
7 9 8 

7 8 8 
7 9 9 

7 8 8 
8 7 7 

7 8 8 
8 7 8 

7 8 8 
8 7 9 

7 8 8 
8 8 7 

7 8 8 
8 8 8 

7 8 8 
8 8 9 

7 8 8 
8 9 7 

7 8 8 
8 9 8 

7 8 8 
8 9 9 

7 8 8 
9 7 7 

7 8 8 
9 7 8 

7 8 8 
9 7 9 

7 8 8 
9 8 7 

7 8 8 
9 8 8 

7 8 8 
9 8 9 

7 8 8 
9 9 7 

7 8 8 
9 9 8 

7 8 8 
9 9 9 

7 8 9 
7 7 7 

7 8 9 
7 7 8 

7 8 9 
7 7 9 

7 8 9 
7 8 7 

7 8 9 
7 8 8 

7 8 9 
7 8 9 

7 8 9 
7 9 7 

7 8 9 
7 9 8 

7 8 9 
7 9 9 

7 8 9 
8 7 7 

7 8 9 
8 7 8 

7 8 9 
8 7 9 

7 8 9 
8 8 7 

7 8 9 
8 8 8 

7 8 9 
8 8 9 

7 8 9 
8 9 7 

7 8 9 
8 9 8 

7 8 9 
8 9 9 

7 8 9 
9 7 7 

7 8 9 
9 7 8 

7 8 9 
9 7 9 

7 8 9 
9 8 7 

7 8 9 
9 8 8 

7 8 9 
9 8 9 

7 8 9 
9 9 7 

7 8 9 
9 9 8 

7 8 9 
9 9 9 

7 9 7 
7 7 7 

7 9 7 
7 7 8 

7 9 7 
7 7 9 

7 9 7 
7 8 7 

7 9 7 
7 8 8 

7 9 7 
7 8 9 

7 9 7 
7 9 7 

7 9 7 
7 9 8 

7 9 7 
7 9 9 

7 9 7 
8 7 7 

7 9 7 
8 7 8 

7 9 7 
8 7 9 

7 9 7 
8 8 7 

7 9 7 
8 8 8 

7 9 7 
8 8 9 

7 9 7 
8 9 7 

7 9 7 
8 9 8 

7 9 7 
8 9 9 

7 9 7 
9 7 7 

7 9 7 
9 7 8 

7 9 7 
9 7 9 

7 9 7 
9 8 7 

7 9 7 
9 8 8 

7 9 7 
9 8 9 

7 9 7 
9 9 7 

7 9 7 
9 9 8 

7 9 7 
9 9 9 

7 9 8 
7 7 7 

7 9 8 
7 7 8 

7 9 8 
7 7 9 

7 9 8 
7 8 7 

7 9 8 
7 8 8 

7 9 8 
7 8 9 

7 9 8 
7 9 7 

7 9 8 
7 9 8 

7 9 8 
7 9 9 

7 9 8 
8 7 7 

7 9 8 
8 7 8 

7 9 8 
8 7 9 

7 9 8 
8 8 7 

7 9 8 
8 8 8 

7 9 8 
8 8 9 

7 9 8 
8 9 7 

7 9 8 
8 9 8 

7 9 8 
8 9 9 

7 9 8 
9 7 7 

7 9 8 
9 7 8 

7 9 8 
9 7 9 

7 9 8 
9 8 7 

7 9 8 
9 8 8 

7 9 8 
9 8 9 

7 9 8 
9 9 7 

7 9 8 
9 9 8 

7 9 8 
9 9 9 

7 9 9 
7 7 7 

7 9 9 
7 7 8 

7 9 9 
7 7 9 

7 9 9 
7 8 7 

7 9 9 
7 8 8 

7 9 9 
7 8 9 

7 9 9 
7 9 7 

7 9 9 
7 9 8 

7 9 9 
7 9 9 

7 9 9 
8 7 7 

7 9 9 
8 7 8 

7 9 9 
8 7 9 

7 9 9 
8 8 7 

7 9 9 
8 8 8 

7 9 9 
8 8 9 

7 9 9 
8 9 7 

7 9 9 
8 9 8 

7 9 9 
8 9 9 

7 9 9 
9 7 7 

7 9 9 
9 7 8 

7 9 9 
9 7 9 

7 9 9 
9 8 7 

7 9 9 
9 8 8 

7 9 9 
9 8 9 

7 9 9 
9 9 7 

7 9 9 
9 9 8 

7 9 9 
9 9 9 

8 7 7 
7 7 7 

8 7 7 
7 7 8 

8 7 7 
7 7 9 

8 7 7 
7 8 7 

8 7 7 
7 8 8 

8 7 7 
7 8 9 

8 7 7 
7 9 7 

8 7 7 
7 9 8 

8 7 7 
7 9 9 

8 7 7 
8 7 7 

8 7 7 
8 7 8 

8 7 7 
8 7 9 

8 7 7 
8 8 7 

8 7 7 
8 8 8 

8 7 7 
8 8 9 

8 7 7 
8 9 7 

8 7 7 
8 9 8 

8 7 7 
8 9 9 

8 7 7 
9 7 7 

8 7 7 
9 7 8 

8 7 7 
9 7 9 

8 7 7 
9 8 7 

8 7 7 
9 8 8 

8 7 7 
9 8 9 

8 7 7 
9 9 7 

8 7 7 
9 9 8 

8 7 7 
9 9 9 

8 7 8 
7 7 7 

8 7 8 
7 7 8 

8 7 8 
7 7 9 

8 7 8 
7 8 7 

8 7 8 
7 8 8 

8 7 8 
7 8 9 

8 7 8 
7 9 7 

8 7 8 
7 9 8 

8 7 8 
7 9 9 

8 7 8 
8 7 7 

8 7 8 
8 7 8 

8 7 8 
8 7 9 

8 7 8 
8 8 7 

8 7 8 
8 8 8 

8 7 8 
8 8 9 

8 7 8 
8 9 7 

8 7 8 
8 9 8 

8 7 8 
8 9 9 

8 7 8 
9 7 7 

8 7 8 
9 7 8 

8 7 8 
9 7 9 

8 7 8 
9 8 7 

8 7 8 
9 8 8 

8 7 8 
9 8 9 

8 7 8 
9 9 7 

8 7 8 
9 9 8 

8 7 8 
9 9 9 

8 7 9 
7 7 7 

8 7 9 
7 7 8 

8 7 9 
7 7 9 

8 7 9 
7 8 7 

8 7 9 
7 8 8 

8 7 9 
7 8 9 

8 7 9 
7 9 7 

8 7 9 
7 9 8 

8 7 9 
7 9 9 

8 7 9 
8 7 7 

8 7 9 
8 7 8 

8 7 9 
8 7 9 

8 7 9 
8 8 7 

8 7 9 
8 8 8 

8 7 9 
8 8 9 

8 7 9 
8 9 7 

8 7 9 
8 9 8 

8 7 9 
8 9 9 

8 7 9 
9 7 7 

8 7 9 
9 7 8 

8 7 9 
9 7 9 

8 7 9 
9 8 7 

8 7 9 
9 8 8 

8 7 9 
9 8 9 

8 7 9 
9 9 7 

8 7 9 
9 9 8 

8 7 9 
9 9 9 

8 8 7 
7 7 7 

8 8 7 
7 7 8 

8 8 7 
7 7 9 

8 8 7 
7 8 7 

8 8 7 
7 8 8 

8 8 7 
7 8 9 

8 8 7 
7 9 7 

8 8 7 
7 9 8 

8 8 7 
7 9 9 

8 8 7 
8 7 7 

8 8 7 
8 7 8 

8 8 7 
8 7 9 

8 8 7 
8 8 7 

8 8 7 
8 8 8 

8 8 7 
8 8 9 

8 8 7 
8 9 7 

8 8 7 
8 9 8 

8 8 7 
8 9 9 

8 8 7 
9 7 7 

8 8 7 
9 7 8 

8 8 7 
9 7 9 

8 8 7 
9 8 7 

8 8 7 
9 8 8 

8 8 7 
9 8 9 

8 8 7 
9 9 7 

8 8 7 
9 9 8 

8 8 7 
9 9 9 

8 8 8 
7 7 7 

8 8 8 
7 7 8 

8 8 8 
7 7 9 

8 8 8 
7 8 7 

8 8 8 
7 8 8 

8 8 8 
7 8 9 

8 8 8 
7 9 7 

8 8 8 
7 9 8 

8 8 8 
7 9 9 

8 8 8 
8 7 7 

8 8 8 
8 7 8 

8 8 8 
8 7 9 

8 8 8 
8 8 7 

8 8 8 
8 8 8 

8 8 8 
8 8 9 

8 8 8 
8 9 7 

8 8 8 
8 9 8 

8 8 8 
8 9 9 

8 8 8 
9 7 7 

8 8 8 
9 7 8 

8 8 8 
9 7 9 

8 8 8 
9 8 7 

8 8 8 
9 8 8 

8 8 8 
9 8 9 

8 8 8 
9 9 7 

8 8 8 
9 9 8 

8 8 8 
9 9 9 

8 8 9 
7 7 7 

8 8 9 
7 7 8 

8 8 9 
7 7 9 

8 8 9 
7 8 7 

8 8 9 
7 8 8 

8 8 9 
7 8 9 

8 8 9 
7 9 7 

8 8 9 
7 9 8 

8 8 9 
7 9 9 

8 8 9 
8 7 7 

8 8 9 
8 7 8 

8 8 9 
8 7 9 

8 8 9 
8 8 7 

8 8 9 
8 8 8 

8 8 9 
8 8 9 

8 8 9 
8 9 7 

8 8 9 
8 9 8 

8 8 9 
8 9 9 

8 8 9 
9 7 7 

8 8 9 
9 7 8 

8 8 9 
9 7 9 

8 8 9 
9 8 7 

8 8 9 
9 8 8 

8 8 9 
9 8 9 

8 8 9 
9 9 7 

8 8 9 
9 9 8 

8 8 9 
9 9 9 

8 9 7 
7 7 7 

8 9 7 
7 7 8 

8 9 7 
7 7 9 

8 9 7 
7 8 7 

8 9 7 
7 8 8 

8 9 7 
7 8 9 

8 9 7 
7 9 7 

8 9 7 
7 9 8 

8 9 7 
7 9 9 

8 9 7 
8 7 7 

8 9 7 
8 7 8 

8 9 7 
8 7 9 

8 9 7 
8 8 7 

8 9 7 
8 8 8 

8 9 7 
8 8 9 

8 9 7 
8 9 7 

8 9 7 
8 9 8 

8 9 7 
8 9 9 

8 9 7 
9 7 7 

8 9 7 
9 7 8 

8 9 7 
9 7 9 

8 9 7 
9 8 7 

8 9 7 
9 8 8 

8 9 7 
9 8 9 

8 9 7 
9 9 7 

8 9 7 
9 9 8 

8 9 7 
9 9 9 

8 9 8 
7 7 7 

8 9 8 
7 7 8 

8 9 8 
7 7 9 

8 9 8 
7 8 7 

8 9 8 
7 8 8 

8 9 8 
7 8 9 

8 9 8 
7 9 7 

8 9 8 
7 9 8 

8 9 8 
7 9 9 

8 9 8 
8 7 7 

8 9 8 
8 7 8 

8 9 8 
8 7 9 

8 9 8 
8 8 7 

8 9 8 
8 8 8 

8 9 8 
8 8 9 

8 9 8 
8 9 7 

8 9 8 
8 9 8 

8 9 8 
8 9 9 

8 9 8 
9 7 7 

8 9 8 
9 7 8 

8 9 8 
9 7 9 

8 9 8 
9 8 7 

8 9 8 
9 8 8 

8 9 8 
9 8 9 

8 9 8 
9 9 7 

8 9 8 
9 9 8 

8 9 8 
9 9 9 

8 9 9 
7 7 7 

8 9 9 
7 7 8 

8 9 9 
7 7 9 

8 9 9 
7 8 7 

8 9 9 
7 8 8 

8 9 9 
7 8 9 

8 9 9 
7 9 7 

8 9 9 
7 9 8 

8 9 9 
7 9 9 

8 9 9 
8 7 7 

8 9 9 
8 7 8 

8 9 9 
8 7 9 

8 9 9 
8 8 7 

8 9 9 
8 8 8 

8 9 9 
8 8 9 

8 9 9 
8 9 7 

8 9 9 
8 9 8 

8 9 9 
8 9 9 

8 9 9 
9 7 7 

8 9 9 
9 7 8 

8 9 9 
9 7 9 

8 9 9 
9 8 7 

8 9 9 
9 8 8 

8 9 9 
9 8 9 

8 9 9 
9 9 7 

8 9 9 
9 9 8 

8 9 9 
9 9 9 

9 7 7 
7 7 7 

9 7 7 
7 7 8 

9 7 7 
7 7 9 

9 7 7 
7 8 7 

9 7 7 
7 8 8 

9 7 7 
7 8 9 

9 7 7 
7 9 7 

9 7 7 
7 9 8 

9 7 7 
7 9 9 

9 7 7 
8 7 7 

9 7 7 
8 7 8 

9 7 7 
8 7 9 

9 7 7 
8 8 7 

9 7 7 
8 8 8 

9 7 7 
8 8 9 

9 7 7 
8 9 7 

9 7 7 
8 9 8 

9 7 7 
8 9 9 

9 7 7 
9 7 7 

9 7 7 
9 7 8 

9 7 7 
9 7 9 

9 7 7 
9 8 7 

9 7 7 
9 8 8 

9 7 7 
9 8 9 

9 7 7 
9 9 7 

9 7 7 
9 9 8 

9 7 7 
9 9 9 

9 7 8 
7 7 7 

9 7 8 
7 7 8 

9 7 8 
7 7 9 

9 7 8 
7 8 7 

9 7 8 
7 8 8 

9 7 8 
7 8 9 

9 7 8 
7 9 7 

9 7 8 
7 9 8 

9 7 8 
7 9 9 

9 7 8 
8 7 7 

9 7 8 
8 7 8 

9 7 8 
8 7 9 

9 7 8 
8 8 7 

9 7 8 
8 8 8 

9 7 8 
8 8 9 

9 7 8 
8 9 7 

9 7 8 
8 9 8 

9 7 8 
8 9 9 

9 7 8 
9 7 7 

9 7 8 
9 7 8 

9 7 8 
9 7 9 

9 7 8 
9 8 7 

9 7 8 
9 8 8 

9 7 8 
9 8 9 

9 7 8 
9 9 7 

9 7 8 
9 9 8 

9 7 8 
9 9 9 

9 7 9 
7 7 7 

9 7 9 
7 7 8 

9 7 9 
7 7 9 

9 7 9 
7 8 7 

9 7 9 
7 8 8 

9 7 9 
7 8 9 

9 7 9 
7 9 7 

9 7 9 
7 9 8 

9 7 9 
7 9 9 

9 7 9 
8 7 7 

9 7 9 
8 7 8 

9 7 9 
8 7 9 

9 7 9 
8 8 7 

9 7 9 
8 8 8 

9 7 9 
8 8 9 

9 7 9 
8 9 7 

9 7 9 
8 9 8 

9 7 9 
8 9 9 

9 7 9 
9 7 7 

9 7 9 
9 7 8 

9 7 9 
9 7 9 

9 7 9 
9 8 7 

9 7 9 
9 8 8 

9 7 9 
9 8 9 

9 7 9 
9 9 7 

9 7 9 
9 9 8 

9 7 9 
9 9 9 

9 8 7 
7 7 7 

9 8 7 
7 7 8 

9 8 7 
7 7 9 

9 8 7 
7 8 7 

9 8 7 
7 8 8 

9 8 7 
7 8 9 

9 8 7 
7 9 7 

9 8 7 
7 9 8 

9 8 7 
7 9 9 

9 8 7 
8 7 7 

9 8 7 
8 7 8 

9 8 7 
8 7 9 

9 8 7 
8 8 7 

9 8 7 
8 8 8 

9 8 7 
8 8 9 

9 8 7 
8 9 7 

9 8 7 
8 9 8 

9 8 7 
8 9 9 

9 8 7 
9 7 7 

9 8 7 
9 7 8 

9 8 7 
9 7 9 

9 8 7 
9 8 7 

9 8 7 
9 8 8 

9 8 7 
9 8 9 

9 8 7 
9 9 7 

9 8 7 
9 9 8 

9 8 7 
9 9 9 

9 8 8 
7 7 7 

9 8 8 
7 7 8 

9 8 8 
7 7 9 

9 8 8 
7 8 7 

9 8 8 
7 8 8 

9 8 8 
7 8 9 

9 8 8 
7 9 7 

9 8 8 
7 9 8 

9 8 8 
7 9 9 

9 8 8 
8 7 7 

9 8 8 
8 7 8 

9 8 8 
8 7 9 

9 8 8 
8 8 7 

9 8 8 
8 8 8 

9 8 8 
8 8 9 

9 8 8 
8 9 7 

9 8 8 
8 9 8 

9 8 8 
8 9 9 

9 8 8 
9 7 7 

9 8 8 
9 7 8 

9 8 8 
9 7 9 

9 8 8 
9 8 7 

9 8 8 
9 8 8 

9 8 8 
9 8 9 

9 8 8 
9 9 7 

9 8 8 
9 9 8 

9 8 8 
9 9 9 

9 8 9 
7 7 7 

9 8 9 
7 7 8 

9 8 9 
7 7 9 

9 8 9 
7 8 7 

9 8 9 
7 8 8 

9 8 9 
7 8 9 

9 8 9 
7 9 7 

9 8 9 
7 9 8 

9 8 9 
7 9 9 

9 8 9 
8 7 7 

9 8 9 
8 7 8 

9 8 9 
8 7 9 

9 8 9 
8 8 7 

9 8 9 
8 8 8 

9 8 9 
8 8 9 

9 8 9 
8 9 7 

9 8 9 
8 9 8 

9 8 9 
8 9 9 

9 8 9 
9 7 7 

9 8 9 
9 7 8 

9 8 9 
9 7 9 

9 8 9 
9 8 7 

9 8 9 
9 8 8 

9 8 9 
9 8 9 

9 8 9 
9 9 7 

9 8 9 
9 9 8 

9 8 9 
9 9 9 

9 9 7 
7 7 7 

9 9 7 
7 7 8 

9 9 7 
7 7 9 

9 9 7 
7 8 7 

9 9 7 
7 8 8 

9 9 7 
7 8 9 

9 9 7 
7 9 7 

9 9 7 
7 9 8 

9 9 7 
7 9 9 

9 9 7 
8 7 7 

9 9 7 
8 7 8 

9 9 7 
8 7 9 

9 9 7 
8 8 7 

9 9 7 
8 8 8 

9 9 7 
8 8 9 

9 9 7 
8 9 7 

9 9 7 
8 9 8 

9 9 7 
8 9 9 

9 9 7 
9 7 7 

9 9 7 
9 7 8 

9 9 7 
9 7 9 

9 9 7 
9 8 7 

9 9 7 
9 8 8 

9 9 7 
9 8 9 

9 9 7 
9 9 7 

9 9 7 
9 9 8 

9 9 7 
9 9 9 

9 9 8 
7 7 7 

9 9 8 
7 7 8 

9 9 8 
7 7 9 

9 9 8 
7 8 7 

9 9 8 
7 8 8 

9 9 8 
7 8 9 

9 9 8 
7 9 7 

9 9 8 
7 9 8 

9 9 8 
7 9 9 

9 9 8 
8 7 7 

9 9 8 
8 7 8 

9 9 8 
8 7 9 

9 9 8 
8 8 7 

9 9 8 
8 8 8 

9 9 8 
8 8 9 

9 9 8 
8 9 7 

9 9 8 
8 9 8 

9 9 8 
8 9 9 

9 9 8 
9 7 7 

9 9 8 
9 7 8 

9 9 8 
9 7 9 

9 9 8 
9 8 7 

9 9 8 
9 8 8 

9 9 8 
9 8 9 

9 9 8 
9 9 7 

9 9 8 
9 9 8 

9 9 8 
9 9 9 

9 9 9 
7 7 7 

9 9 9 
7 7 8 

9 9 9 
7 7 9 

9 9 9 
7 8 7 

9 9 9 
7 8 8 

9 9 9 
7 8 9 

9 9 9 
7 9 7 

9 9 9 
7 9 8 

9 9 9 
7 9 9 

9 9 9 
8 7 7 

9 9 9 
8 7 8 

9 9 9 
8 7 9 

9 9 9 
8 8 7 

9 9 9 
8 8 8 

9 9 9 
8 8 9 

9 9 9 
8 9 7 

9 9 9 
8 9 8 

9 9 9 
8 9 9 

9 9 9 
9 7 7 

9 9 9 
9 7 8 

9 9 9 
9 7 9 

9 9 9 
9 8 7 

9 9 9 
9 8 8 

9 9 9 
9 8 9 

9 9 9 
9 9 7 

9 9 9 
9 9 8 

9 9 9 
9 9 9
```